# How do I figure out what is causing Data IO spikes on my Azure SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a Azure SQL production database that runs at around 10-20% DTU usage on average, however, I get DTU spikes that take it upwards of 100% at times. Here is a sample from the past 1 hour:

[image]

I realize this could be a rouge query, so I switched over to the **Query Performance Insight** tab, and I find the following from the past 24 hours:

[image]

This chart makes sense with regards to the CPU usage line. Query **3780** takes the majority of at CPU, as expected with my application. The **Overall DTU** (red) line seems to follow this correctly (minus the spikes).

However, in the **DTU Components** charts I can see large **Data IO** spikes occurring that coincide with the **Overall DTU** spikes. Switching over to the **TOP 5 queries by Data IO**, I see the following:

[image]

This seems to indicate that there are no queries that are using high amounts of **Data IO**.

How do I find out where this **Data IO** usage is coming from?

Finally, I see that there is this one, "odd ball" query (**7966**) listed under the **TOP 5 queries by Data IO** with only 5 executions. Selecting it shows the following:

[image]

```
SELECT StatMan([SC0], [SC1], [SC2], [SB0000])
    FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT [SC0], [SC1], [SC2], step_direction([SC0]) over (order by NULL) AS [SB0000]
    FROM (SELECT [UserId] AS [SC0], [Type] AS [SC1], [Id] AS [SC2] FROM [dbo].[Cipher] TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (1.828756e+000 PERCENT)
    WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ) AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL_HELPER
ORDER BY [SC0], [SC1], [SC2], [SB0000] ) AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL 
OPTION (MAXDOP 16)
```

What is this query?

This does not look like any query that my application has created/uses. The timestamps on the details chart seem to line up with the approximate times of the overall Data IO spikes (just prior to 6am) which leads me to think this query has something to do with all of this.

Are there any other tools can I use to help isolate this issue?

Comment: Have you tried turning AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS off? I believe this is an internal SQL process to update statistical meta data.

Comment: @DanielG I have not tried that yet. I can try disabling stats on table `dbo.Ciphers` with [`sp_autostats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-autostats-transact-sql) and see if that changes anything, though I am unsure as to what effect that will then have on that table since `dbo.Ciphers` is very high traffic table within the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is updating statistics..this occurs when this setting `AUTO UPDATE STATISTICS`  is on..This should be kept on  and you can't turn it off..this is a best practice..

You should update stats manually only when when you see a query not performing well and stats are off for that query..

Also below are some rules when SQL will update stats automatically for you

- When a table with no rows gets a row
- When 500 rows are changed to a table that is less than 500 rows
- When 20% + 500 are changed in a table greater than 500 rows

By ‘change’ we mean if a row is inserted, updated or deleted. So, yes, even the automatically-created statistics get updated and maintained as the data changes.There were some changes to these rules in recent versions and sql can update stats more often

**References:**
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/understanding-when-statistics-will-automatically-update/

Comment: I've been updating statistics on a nightly basis to help mitigate this problem now. You mentioned "You should update stats manually only when when you see a query not performing well and stats are off for that query..". How do I determine which queries are performing badly because of statistics issues?

Comment: @kspearrin:One way would be to check estimates..If you see this image,estimated rows and actual rows are different:https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG0ll.png

Comment: Just as FYI:we used to update stats,rebuild indexes on weekends,not nightly..but this again depends on your workload ,so a nightly schedule might suit you:Check out this link as well https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19130/when-to-update-statistics

Answer (score 1):

It seems that query is part of the automatic update of statistics process. To mitigate the impact of this process on production you can regularly update statistics and indexes using runbooks  as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2016/07/03/how-to-maintain-azure-sql-indexes-and-statistics/). Run sp_updatestats to immediately try to mitigate the impact of this process.

Comment: Is this just a manual way for maintaining statistics? It seems like SQL Azure is trying to do it for my automatically but is just bad at it? Or are my statistics just off and need to be "refreshed". Should I be turning on `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS` if I plan to use something like your suggested script on a nightly/weekly basis?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server and Azure SQL Database usually try to do maintenance on statistics using s sample method when an schedule task does not exist for that.  Try to identify what could be the maintenance windows of your applications and create a runbook to run during those hours to defragment indexes and updates statistics. The following article shows you how to create a runbook. https://sqlperformance.com/2017/06/azure/automation-methods